# Microsoft Graph - Issue with OneDrive subfolder image search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have an issue when searching for images scoped on a subfolder and it's children. The same issue does not seem to occur when searching for text files.

Example: My OneDrive looks like this:

```
Root/
    subdirectory/
        image.png
        textfile.txt
```

If I query:

`/me/drive/items/{id-of-subdirectory}/search(q='textfile')`

my result will contain the file that I'm searching for (with the addition of the subdirectory itself):

```
"value": [
    {
        "id": "id-of-subdirectory",
        "name": "subdirectory"
    },
    {
        "id": "id-of-textfile.txt",
        "name": "textfile.txt"
    }
]
```

But if I query for the image:

`/me/drive/items/{id-of-subdirectory}/search(q='image')`

my result doesn't contain the image (only the subdirectory)

```
"value": [
    {
        "id": "id-of-subdirectory",
        "name": "subdirectory"
    }
]
```

Does anyone know the reason for why the image isn't showing up in the search result?

Is there another way to perform searching scoped to a particular subfolder and it's children?